# Sort nested object in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm using the following mapping:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "blogpost": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "string"}
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "comment": { "type": "string"  },
            "date":    { "type": "date"    }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example of document:

```
PUT /my_index/blogpost/1
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "comments": [ 
    {
      "comment": "Great article",
      "date":    "2014-09-01"
    },
    {
      "comment": "More like this please",
      "date":    "2014-10-22"
    },
    {
      "comment": "Visit my website",
      "date":    "2014-07-02"
    },
    {
      "comment": "Awesome",
      "date":    "2014-08-23"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is how to retrieve this document and sort the nested object "comments" by "date"? the result:

```
PUT /my_index/blogpost/1
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "comments": [ 
    {
      "comment": "Awesome",
      "date":    "2014-07-23"
    },
    {
      "comment": "Visit my website",
      "date":    "2014-08-02"
    },
    {
      "comment": "Great article",
      "date":    "2014-09-01"
    },
    {
      "comment": "More like this please",
      "date":    "2014-10-22"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what version of ES you are using? this is weird, I followed [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html) and it is not working. I am not sure if this is bug, might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9305)

Comment: That's not my question, i don't want to filter "by" nested field, i want to sort "the" nested field. ES version 1.7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to `sort` on the [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-request-inner-hits.html) to sort the `nested objects`. This will give you the desired output

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "sort": {
          "comments.date": {
            "order": "asc"
          }
        },
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "title"
  ]
}
```

I am using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) to get only `"title"` as `comments` will be retrieved inside `inner_hit` but you can avoid that if you want

`size` is 5 because default value is 3 and we have 4 objects in the given example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So `size` here only limits how many comments we want to display (sorted by date) ?

So if I specify `"size": 1` then I'll get the first (the oldest) message, aren't I ? 

Thx in advance !